# Automorphism group of the ring $\mathbb{F}_3\left[t,\frac{1}{t}\right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R=\mathbb{F}_3\left[t,\frac{1}{t}\right]$ be a ring.

What is the simplest form of $\mathrm{Aut}(R)$ ?

---

Here $t$ is a variable and $R$ is the smallest ring contained in field $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$, which contain $t$ and $\frac{1}{t}$. I tried to find $R^*$ and used this to restrict size of $\mathrm{Aut}(R)$, but it didn't give me an answer. Of course, I am looking for $\mathbb{F}_3$-automorphism.

Comment: Time to start including your thoughts in your questions.

Comment: This is a good question. $t$ is a variable, and you're asking for the ring of $F_3$-algebra automorphisms, right?

Comment: @user208259, yes $t$ is a variable and $R$ is the smallest ring contained in field $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$, which contain $t$ and $\frac{1}{t}$. I tried to find $R^*$ and used this to restrict size of $\mathrm{Aut}(R)$, but it didn't give me an answer. Of course, I am looking for $\mathbb{F}_3$-automorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general nonzero element of $R$ can be uniquely written in the form $t^a f(t)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(t)$ is a polynomial with $f(0) \ne 0$. This shows that the invertible elements of $R$ are precisely the monomials $ct^a$, with $c \ne 0$.

Since $R$ is the localization of $F_3[t]$ which inverts the element $t$, an endomorphism of $R$ corresponds to any morphism $F_3[t] \to R$ which takes $t$ to an invertible element of $R$. It is clear that if $|a| > 1$ (or $a = 0$) and $t \mapsto ct^a$, then the image of the corresponding endomorphism of $R$ will be contained in $F_3[t^a,1/t^a]$ and therefore it cannot be an automorphism. Thus the only possibilities are $t \mapsto t, 2t, 1/t, 2/t$.

Since all of these automorphisms have order $1$ or $2$, it follows that $\operatorname{Aut}(R)$, as an abstract group, is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.